# How to setup multiple stores with different 2 domain name using same magento 2 backend?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multiple

I want to set up 2 websites domains using 2 different domain names.

I can create 2 different websites from the Magento backend.

But I want to point to 2 different websites from 2 domain names.

Ex - [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) , [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com).

Hope someone already achieves this, Please advise me on how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.4.2+ update the `index.php` file in `/pub/` with the code below where *domain1dotcom* and *mydomaindotcom* are the store names for the Magento shops served by the respective domains.

```
<?php

try {
    require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.domain1.com':
        $params = $_SERVER;
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'domain1dotcom';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
        $bootstrap->run($app);
        break;
    case 'www.mydomain.com':
        $params = $_SERVER;
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'mydomaindotcom';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
        $bootstrap->run($app);
        break;

    default:
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
        $bootstrap->run($app);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer, Is it working for 2.2 version also?

Comment: Yes - need to change index,php in magento root folder.

Comment: thank you very much